# Where to hook up my carburetor hoses on a 1998 Yamaha Breeze

Tags: carburetor, yamaha, atv

1998 Yamaha breeze Four wheeler. Where do the carburetor hoses hook up

Comment: Any photos of carb, hoses and fittings?

Comment: Yes can make some